# checking if FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission is granted allways returns false

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, foreground-service

Having followed the migration notes and added the following line to the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

I could not figure out why I am getting a failing test case where the permission `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` is not granted (at least when it's being checked at run-time).

Based on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration#tya), which states that `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE`should be automatically granted by the system.

> apps wanting to use foreground services must now request the
> FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission first. This is a normal permission, so
> the system automatically grants it to the requesting app.

Can somebody explain why my test case (which uses a variant of the following code) is failing?

```
assertEquals(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"), PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

**Yet!** I do not have any `SecurityException` thrown. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is failing because you probably run it on device with API < 28. This method field works only on API 28 and up. If you write as you should `Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` instead of plain string, Android Studio will warn you.

Answer (score 4):

`FOREGROUND_SERVICE` is not a `dangerous` permission. Hence, it has nothing to do with the runtime permission system and methods like `checkSelfPermission()`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, there is no need to check it at runtime. However the method should return true on API >= 28 if permission is added in manifest.